# How to make HTTP requests from different clients appear that they came from the same IP address?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I'm using a 3rd-party API that invalidates the OAuth token if the requests came from different IP addresses. This is causing issues because the service runs on multiple hosts.

Ideally, I want the option that only the requests to this particular API will be routed through a single IP.

I thought about setting up a proxy server, but I'm concerned that I won't be able to scale this proxy beyond 1 machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The right answer probbaly really is either a proxy, or separate OAuth tokens for each machine instead of a single shared one. If you were running your own physical network, you could just put all your hosts behind a NAT router, but I'm pretty sure that's not at all easy to do with GCP, and not something Google wants you to do.

Comment: Of course you can pretty easily use the proxy server only for the requests to this particular API, rather than for all HTTP traffic. For example, [here's how to do that with the `requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) library.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about NAT, but I wasn't very familiar with the concept. I'll look into it a bit more. Maybe I could have a NAT just for the proxy(ies).

Comment: Having a NAT for just the proxies would require either having a very complicated routing table, or having two network interfaces for every host so you can NAT one but not the other. It's probably not what you want to do. (Also, a NAT really is similar to a proxy, just one level down the protocol stack. If you're looking to scale out massively to the point where a proxy won't work, then you're talking multiple tiers of NAT routers, which quickly becomes an ops nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal option here would of course be to obtain an OAuth token for each machine. (Or, even better, to get the service to allow you to share a token across IPs.) But I assume there's some reason you can't do that.

In which case you probably *do* want a proxy server here.

The option that only the requests to this particular API be routed through that proxy is dead simple. Set up an explicit proxy rather than a transparent one, and specify that explicit proxy for these particular methods.

Since you haven't shown us, or even described, your code, I can't show you how to do that with whatever library you're using, but [here's how to do it with `requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies), and it's not much harder with the stdlib `urllib` or most other third-party libraries.

But, for completeness: It's not at all impossible to make the separate machines appear to have the same IP address, as long as all of you machines are behind a router that you have control over. In fact, that's exactly what you get with a typical home DSL/cable setup via [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation): each machine has its own internal-only address, but they all share one public address. But it's probably not what you want. For one thing, if your machines are actually GCP hosts, you don't control the router, and you may not even be able to control whether they're on the same network (in case you were thinking of running a software router to pipe them all through). Also, NAT causes all kinds of problems for servers. And, since your worry here is scaling, using NAT is a nightmare once you have to scale beyond a single subnet. And even more so if these instances are meant to be servers (which seems likely, if you're running them on GCP). And finally, to use NAT to talk just to one service, you either need very complicated routing tables, or an extra network interface per machine (that you can put behind a different router). So, I doubt it's what you actually want here.

Comment: another option (if the machines are controllable by a single router) is you can route all the traffic to the API through a single IP. This is much easier than NAT

Comment: @bansi That _is_ NAT. How else would the responses get back to the specific machines that issued the requests, if not a NAT table?

Comment: One token for each machine is not an option unfortunately. I think I'll go with the single proxy for now, it's the easiest in terms of setup and maintenance.